# Backtrace full of duplicate entries when debugging Rust firmware for STM32 with ARM GDB

Tags: rust, gdb, embedded, stm32, cortex-m

### What am I doing

I'm trying to use Rust to make a firmware for STM32F103 board and debug it using GDB.

My project more or less follows [blinky.rs](https://github.com/stm32-rs/stm32f1xx-hal/blob/master/examples/blinky.rs) example from https://github.com/stm32-rs/stm32f1xx-hal cargo crate, including Cargo.toml. One exception being is me using `cortex-m-semihosting` and `panic-semihosting` crates.

**EDIT**: `src/main.rs`:

```rust
#![deny(unsafe_code)]

#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use panic_halt as _;
use cortex_m_rt::entry;

use stm32f1xx_hal::{
    prelude::*,
    pac,
};

use embedded_hal::digital::v2::OutputPin;

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let dp = pac::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let mut rcc = dp.RCC.constrain();

    let mut gpioc = dp.GPIOC.split(&mut rcc.apb2);
    let mut led = gpioc.pc13.into_push_pull_output(&mut gpioc.crh);

    led.set_low().unwrap();

    loop {}
}
```

My `.cargo/config` is like following:

```
[target.thumbv7m-none-eabi]
runner = 'arm-none-eabi-gdb'

rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-arg=-Tlink.x", # also tried old way with gcc linker, no difference
]

[build]
target = "thumbv7m-none-eabi"
```

`Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "blue-pill-rust"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[[bin]]
name = "blue-pill-rust"
test = false
bench = false

[profile.release]
opt-level = "s"
debug = true

[dependencies.stm32f1xx-hal]
version = "0.5.3"
features = ["stm32f103", "rt", "medium"]

[dependencies.cortex-m]
version = "0.6.2"

[dependencies.cortex-m-rt]
version = "0.6.12"

[dependencies]
panic-halt = "0.2.0"
```

### What happens

I'm using GDB directly to flash the firmware (property of BlackMagicProbe debugger), but same result occurred with OpenOCD:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gdb
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.3.1
...

(gdb) target extended-remote /dev/ttyBmpGdb
Remote debugging using /dev/ttyBmpGdb
(gdb) attach 1
Attaching to Remote target
warning: No executable has been specified and target does not support
determining executable automatically.  Try using the "file" command.
0x0800448c in ?? ()
(gdb) file target/thumbv7m-none-eabi/release/blue-pill-rust
Reading symbols from target/thumbv7m-none-eabi/release/blue-pill-rust...
(gdb) load
...
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x8000130: file src/main.rs, line 27.
Starting program: /media/data/projects/rust/blue-pill-rust/target/thumbv7m-none-eabi/release/blue-pill-rust
Note: automatically using hardware breakpoints for read-only addresses.

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at src/main.rs:27
27      #[entry]
(gdb) step
blue_pill_rust::__cortex_m_rt_main () at src/main.rs:33
33          hprintln!("hello, world!").unwrap();
(gdb) next
hello, world!
warning: (Internal error: pc 0x80004d2 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)
warning: (Internal error: pc 0x80004d2 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)
warning: (Internal error: pc 0x80004d2 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)
warning: (Internal error: pc 0x80004d2 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)
warning: (Internal error: pc 0x80004d2 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)
warning: (Internal error: pc 0x80004d2 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)

36          let cp = cortex_m::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
(gdb)
```

Same issue repeats for other lines of code every time I do `next`, so it shouldn't be a problem with ARM semihosting (which prints "Hello, World!").

I tried disabling link time optimizations in Cargo.toml (`lto = false`). This seemed to fix the issue with this error, but the main problem of the question persists.

Anyway, if I check a `backtrace` after `next`ing a few times, I get the following picture:

```
(gdb) bt
...
#407 0x08000152 in blue_pill_rust::__cortex_m_rt_main () at src/main.rs:31
#408 0x08000152 in blue_pill_rust::__cortex_m_rt_main () at src/main.rs:31
#409 0x08000152 in blue_pill_rust::__cortex_m_rt_main () at src/main.rs:31
#410 0x08000152 in blue_pill_rust::__cortex_m_rt_main () at src/main.rs:31
#411 0x08000152 in blue_pill_rust::__cortex_m_rt_main () at src/main.rs:31
#412 0x08000152 in blue_pill_rust::__cortex_m_rt_main () at src/main.rs:31
#413 0x08000152 in blue_pill_rust::__cortex_m_rt_main () at src/main.rs:31
#414 0x08000152 in blue_pill_rust::__cortex_m_rt_main () at src/main.rs:31
...
```

and this goes further than a 1000 entries.

I tried replacing 0 level of optimization with `"s"` (with lto also disabled) in Cargo.toml. It results in similar issue, yet a bit more verbose one:

```
...
#1576 blue_pill_rust::__cortex_m_rt_main () at src/main.rs:34
#1577 0x080001e2 in cortex_m::interrupt::enable ()
    at /home/superprower/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cortex-m-0.6.2/src/interrupt.rs:49
#1578 cortex_m::interrupt::free (f=...)
    at /home/superprower/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cortex-m-0.6.2/src/interrupt.rs:75
#1579 cortex_m::peripheral::Peripherals::take ()
    at /home/superprower/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cortex-m-0.6.2/src/peripheral/mod.rs:152
#1580 blue_pill_rust::__cortex_m_rt_main () at src/main.rs:34
#1581 0x080001e2 in cortex_m::interrupt::enable ()
    at /home/superprower/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cortex-m-0.6.2/src/interrupt.rs:49
#1582 cortex_m::interrupt::free (f=...)
    at /home/superprower/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cortex-m-0.6.2/src/interrupt.rs:75
#1583 cortex_m::peripheral::Peripherals::take ()
    at /home/superprower/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cortex-m-0.6.2/src/peripheral/mod.rs:152
#1584 blue_pill_rust::__cortex_m_rt_main () at src/main.rs:34
#1585 0x080001e2 in cortex_m::interrupt::enable ()
    at /home/superprower/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cortex-m-0.6.2/src/interrupt.rs:49
#1586 cortex_m::interrupt::free (f=...)
    at /home/superprower/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cortex-m-0.6.2/src/interrupt.rs:75
#1587 cortex_m::peripheral::Peripherals::take ()
    at /home/superprower/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cortex-m-0.6.2/src/peripheral/mod.rs:152
#1588 blue_pill_rust::__cortex_m_rt_main () at src/main.rs:34
#1589 0x080001e2 in cortex_m::interrupt::enable ()
    at /home/superprower/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cortex-m-0.6.2/src/interrupt.rs:49
#1590 cortex_m::interrupt::free (f=...)
    at /home/superprower/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cortex-m-0.6.2/src/interrupt.rs:75
#1591 cortex_m::peripheral::Peripherals::take ()
    at /home/superprower/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cortex-m-0.6.2/src/peripheral/mod.rs:152
#1592 blue_pill_rust::__cortex_m_rt_main () at src/main.rs:34
#1593 0x080001e2 in cortex_m::interrupt::enable ()
    at /home/superprower/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cortex-m-0.6.2/src/interrupt.rs:49
#1594 cortex_m::interrupt::free (f=...)
    at /home/superprower/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cortex-m-0.6.2/src/interrupt.rs:75
#1595 cortex_m::peripheral::Peripherals::take ()
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
    at /home/superprower/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cortex-m-0.6.2/src/peripheral/mod.rs:152
#1596 blue_pill_rust::__cortex_m_rt_main () at src/main.rs:34
#1597 0x080001e2 in cortex_m::interrupt::enable ()
    at /home/superprower/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cortex-m-0.6.2/src/interrupt.rs:49
#1598 cortex_m::interrupt::free (f=...)
    at /home/superprower/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cortex-m-0.6.2/src/interrupt.rs:75
#1599 cortex_m::peripheral::Peripherals::take ()
    at /home/superprower/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cortex-m-0.6.2/src/peripheral/mod.rs:152
#1600 blue_pill_rust::__cortex_m_rt_main () at src/main.rs:34
#1601 0x080001e2 in cortex_m::interrupt::enable ()
...
```

It is as if when returning from the functions, records aren't being cleaned up or something.

### Environment

My GDB (as well as other cross-compile utilities) come from [Arch Linux Repositories](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/arm-none-eabi-gdb/):

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gdb -v
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.3.1

$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-none-eabi
Configured with: /build/arm-none-eabi-gcc/src/gcc-9.2.0/configure --target=arm-none-eabi --prefix=/usr --with-sysroot=/usr/arm-none-eabi --with-native-system-header-dir=/include --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-plugins --disable-decimal-float --disable-libffi --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-threads --disable-tls --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-system-zlib --with-newlib --with-headers=/usr/arm-none-eabi/include --with-python-dir=share/gcc-arm-none-eabi --with-gmp --with-mpfr --with-mpc --with-isl --with-libelf --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-pkgversion='Arch Repository' --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --with-multilib-list=rmprofile
Thread model: single
gcc version 9.2.0 (Arch Repository)
```

and are up to date.

Any help with troubleshooting this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think they are duplicate entries and not actual call trace? Please post the sources. Please post an [MCVE] so others can reproduce the problem, please post the sources of `src/main.rs:27`. What is your question? Did you try stepping through the debugger to locate the exact instruction when the "bug" occurs? Did you try stepping through your code execution?

Comment: @KamilCuk : they are not duplicate entries, you are correct. However, I think it's unusual for a program to produce a stack trace of more than a thousand elements in a single step, especially containing records of the function the step occurred in.

As for example, I have reduced my code to just enabling the LED based on example I linked and posted it.